# postprocessing in inference.py doesn't work when I created a ML pipeline from Sagemaker

Tags: pipeline, amazon-sagemaker, post-processing

I am creating a ML pipeline from Sagemaker.
As the following code, I added an inference.py to do the post-processing which will be called during an invocation in the endpoint. However, the output_handler() in inference.py was never called during an invocation.

```
from sagemaker.workflow.step_collections import CreateModelStep
from sagemaker.tensorflow.model import TensorFlowModel

model = TensorFlowModel(
    role=role,
    model_data=step_train_model.properties.ModelArtifacts.S3ModelArtifacts,
    source_dir = 'Scripts/',
    entry_point = "inference.py",
    framework_version=tensorflow_version,
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
)

step_create_model = CreateModelStep(
    name="Create-Transaction-Categorization-Model",
    model=model,
    inputs=sagemaker.inputs.CreateModelInput(instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge"),
)
```

In contrast, if I build a model without using pipeline (see below). The postprocessing works as expected.
I am not sure what I have done wrong. Thanks.

```
cat_estimator = tf.TensorFlow(
    entry_point = "dnn.py",
    role = role,
    instance_count = 1,
    instance_type = "ml.p3.2xlarge",
    framework_version = "2.8",
    py_version = "py39",
    model_dir = '/opt/ml/model/',
    output_path = model_path,
    distribution = {"parameter_server": {"enabled": True}}
)

cat_estimator.fit(training_data_uri)
model = cat_estimator.create_model(role = role, source_dir = "Scripts", entry_point = "inference.py")
```

Should I use inference pipeline? It requires to build a post-processing container which is much complicated than just providing an inference.py script.

Comment: What version of the SageMaker SDK are you using? Can you test upgrading the SageMaker SDK : pip install sagemaker --upgrade. I would also check to see the model tar ball that the SDK created has the inference.py added.

Answer (score 1):

I got help from AWS support. There are two changes to be made.
Btw, the sagemaker sdk version is 2.116.0.

First, in my previous code. I used sagemaker_session = sagemaker.session.Session() as the session parameter. It is now changed to **sagemaker_session = PipelineSession()**.

Second,

```
step_create_model = CreateModelStep(
name="Create-Transaction-Categorization-Model",
model=model,
inputs=sagemaker.inputs.CreateModelInput(instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge"),
```

)

is replaced with

```
from sagemaker.workflow.model_step import ModelStep
step_create_model = ModelStep(
     name="Create-Transaction-Categorization-Model",
    step_args=tensorflow_model.create(instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge")
)
```